# IBM Worklight - Limitations of Worklight Studio for Developers

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

is there any documented limitations of Worklight Studio for developer?
Or any differences between Worklight Studio for developer and the Worklight Studio provided after the product purchase?

Comment: and worklight studio is?

Answer (score 1):

@Alastair Pitts: [IBM Worklight Studio](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/components/mobile-development-platform/) is a plug-in for the Eclipse IDE, that allows you to develop applications for the [IBM Worklight Mobile Application Platform](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/).

The differences between the [IBM Worklight Developer/Consumer/Enterprise editions](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/getstart/c_wl_editions.html) are:

**Developer:**

- Developer edition is licensed for development use only, free download
- Does not contain the [application authenticity feature](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/dev/c_ibm_worklight_app_authentication_overview.html)

**Consumer/Enterprise:**

- Enterprise edition has pricing metrics aligned with Business-to-Enterprise (B2E) purchasing patterns.
- Consumer edition has pricing metrics aligned with Business-to-Consumer (B2C) purchasing patterns.
- Contains the [application authenticity feature](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/dev/c_ibm_worklight_app_authentication_overview.html)

Comment: Thanks Idar, to my knowledge purchasing either Consumer or Enterprise edition, there's no limit on how many Studio are used.
The difference is in the Server component, in case of Enterprise edition each Worklight server instance has to be purchased, while with Consumer, there is no limit on Worklight Server installation.
Am I right?
What do you mean with "pricing metric" ?

Comment: It's just "Idan", not "Idar". These type of questions can only be answered and should be directed to IBM, contact an IBM Worklight sales reprasentative: https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/iwm/web/signup.do?source=raq&S_TACT=109HE02W&lang=en_US

Comment: @GiovanniVigorelli, if this answer helped you resolve your problem, please mark it as Answered.