# IBM Worklight - Can commercial apps be created using the Developer Edition?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Can we build commercial apps using the IBM Worklight free Developer Edition?

I searched the IBM official site and I sensed that we have to buy the license to develop commercial apps. But, can someone please clarify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Legally speaking:** [No, you cannot.](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/sla/sladb.nsf/lilookup/02C11A39525DAD3C85257A17003CADC9?opendocument&li_select=FC2F043D1B752D2B85257A17003CADC6)

> Non-Production Limitation
>
> The Program can only be deployed as part of the Licensee's internal
>   development and test environment for internal non-production
>   activities, including but not limited to testing, performance tuning,
>   fault diagnosis, internal benchmarking, staging, quality assurance
>   activity and/or developing internally used additions or extensions to
>   the Program using published application programming interfaces.
>   Licensee is not authorized to use any part of the Program for any
>   other purposes without acquiring the appropriate production
>   entitlements.

**Technically speaking:** you could create an application that does not utilize Worklight features that in order to use them in a production environment, you'd have to buy the Consumer or Enterprise Edition of IBM  Worklight.

By doing so you will lose:

- The ability to install Worklight Server on an application server
- The ability to utilize Worklight Adapters for backend connectivity, that rely on Worklight Server
- The ability to secure your application using numerous built-in security features (application authenticity, device provisioning, ...)
- The ability to manage your applications (notify, disable, ...)
- The ability to remotely update (Direct Update) your applications
- The ability to leverage Worklight's unified Push Notifications
- The ability to see operational analytics
- ... and the list goes on.

Instead, you will have to rely on AJAX requests and spend time on (re-)implementing various aspects required for an application (but that's also of course depending on the scope and  purpose of the application).

Also see:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030963/ibm-worklight-license-is-worklight-free-to-use/17031953#17031953
- [IBM Worklight - Limitations of Worklight Studio for Developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074897/ibm-worklight-limitations-of-worklight-studio-for-developers/16075570#16075570)

For any inquiries about Worklight I would suggest to contact IBM:

- https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/iwm/web/signup.do?source=raq&S_TACT=109HE02W&lang=en_US